# gitginore cannot ignore the folder, an error occurred while adding them

Tags: git

I want to use `add .`  to add all of the files. However, I meet

```
error: open("project1/codes/Project1/.vs/Project1/v15/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'project1/codes/Project1/.vs/Project1/v15/Browse.VC.opendb'
fatal: adding files failed
```

I write a .gitignore, but in vain. I wonder what mistake I have done?
[image]

Comment: Was `.vs` by any chance already checked in before? If you add it to `.gitignore` after git started tracking it, it won't be ignored.

Comment: And if `.vs/*` are not already tracked, make sure your `.gitignore` file is plain text in UTF-8, not UTF-16 or some other encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you dont have the permissions.

Check the permissions for that folder or run the command with sudo.

Comment: I just want to ignore this folder instead of opening it.

Answer (score 0):

I use *VSCODE* to write a new `.gitignore` instead of using the Windows notebook. It really works.

I have used PowerShell to  like this:

```
echo ".vs/" >> .gitignore
```

this way also has error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `.vs` folder has already been tracked and that could explain why adding it to the `.gitignore` file is not enough to prevent it from being added.

You will find in this issue: [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) how to really ignore your folder so that it will not be added by the `add .` command.

Read carefully to pick the most suitable solution because, depending on your needs, you can untrack the folder or not (both solutions are explained in  the issue linked).